# Unable to Export Kriging Prediction Map

Tags: r, kriging, ggplot2

I have performed Kriging using the `autoKrige` function, that is part of the `automap` package in R.

I obtained this as my output

[image]

I have realized that maybe the reason why I can not export the Kriging prediction plot is because the grid that  I setup (to performed kriging) is somehow wrong.

```
library(rgdal)     
library(ggplot2)   
library(ggmap)
library(GISTools)
library(sp)
library(gstat)
library(automap)
library(raster)  
library(reshape2)

all.data<-read.csv("E:/Juan Arango/All_Data_Fall_17.csv", header=TRUE)
all.data
dput(data.frame(all.data)[,c("Lat","Lon","Secchi.Disk")])
coordinates(all.data)<- ~ Lat + Lon
class(all.data)

#Setup the gird
grid <- raster(extent(WWWL.Shape))
res(grid) <- 5
proj4string(grid)<-proj4string(WWWL.Shape)
gridpolygon <- rasterToPolygons(grid)
dry.grid <- intersect(WWWL.Shape, gridpolygon)
plot(dry.grid)

#AutoKriging SD
SDVar <- autofitVariogram(Secchi.Disk~1, all.data)
summary(SDVar)
plot(SDVar)
SDKrig <- autoKrige(Secchi.Disk~1, all.data, dry.grid)
plot(SDKrig)
plot(SDKrig$krige_output[,"var1.pred"])
```

Output `dput(data.frame(all.data)[,c("Lat","Lon","Secchi.Disk")])`

```
>dput(data.frame(all.data)[,c("Lat","Lon","Secchi.Disk")])
structure(list(Lat = c(334374, 334381, 334391, 334423, 334426, 
334431, 334465, 334455, 334444, 334481, 334481, 334489), Lon = c(4088957, 
4089003, 4089040, 4089041, 4088984, 4088965, 4089025, 4088982, 
4088924, 4088929, 4089004, 4089039), Secchi.Disk = c(18L, 15L, 
16L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 17L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 16L)), .Names = c("Lat", 
"Lon", "Secchi.Disk"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
```

Output `plot(SDKrig$krige_output[,"var1.pred"])`
[image]

Any ideas on how fix this? Could it be related to way I setup the grid?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exporting kriging prediction map in .asc format?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92566/exporting-kriging-prediction-map-in-asc-format)

Comment: @AndreSilva thank you for your response. I  have realized that maybe the issue that I am having is how I setup the grid that I am using... maybe?

Comment: After you edited your question it became unclear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: @AndreSilva sorry for the confusion. Please allow me to explain you better. I used the  autoKrige function in order to performed Kriging (as I mentioned in my original post). After reading your comment, I realized that maybe the reason why I can not export the kriging prediction plot (created by using the autoKrige function) is because the grid that I setup and is somehow not right? So I guess my question now is, is there something wrong with the grid that I created? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$krige_output` component is a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` object holding the estimates and the standard  errors. You can then export this to shapefile (or anything else) in the usual ways.

Reproducible example from the help:

```
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) =~ x+y
data(meuse.grid)
gridded(meuse.grid) =~ x+y

# Ordinary kriging, no new_data object
kriging_result = autoKrige(zinc~1, meuse)
plot(kriging_result$krige_output)
```

will plot the kriging predictions:

[image]

```
plot(kriging_result$krige_output[,"var1.pred"])
plot(kriging_result$krige_output[,"var1.var"])
```

similarly plot the predictions and the variances.

Comment: thank you for your response. However, after using  plot(kriging_result$krige_output[,"var1.pred"]) I only get the .shp file that I imported with the grid, not the  kriging predictions plot witht the legend and colors. If there anything else that I need to add to that code?

Comment: Without seeing some of **your** code we can't help much.

Comment: I have realized that maybe the issue that I am having is how a setup the grid that I am using... maybe?

Answer (score 3):

You will not be able to export symbology from the plot function, only the raster(s). This is not a shapefile (polygon, point, line) but rather a raster format. Whereas there are steps to convert to a point object that can be exported as a shapefile, this is not desirable.

The class of the output from automap::autoKrige is a SpatialPixelsDataFrame (sp raster class object) and can be exported to a raster format using writeGDAL in rgdal or writeRaster in the raster package(s).

```
library(automap)
  data(meuse)
  coordinates(meuse) =~ x+y
  data(meuse.grid)
  gridded(meuse.grid) =~ x+y

kriging_result = autoKrige(zinc~1, meuse)
  class(kriging_result$krige_output)
  names(kriging_result$krige_output)

# export using raster
library(raster)
writeRaster(raster(kriging_result$krige_output, "var1.pred"), "pred.var.tif", options="COMPRESS=LZW")

# export using rgdal
library(rgdal)
writeGDAL(kriging_result$krige_output[,"var1.pred"], "pred.var.tif")
```